# The chapters appear twice in the bookmark

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

First of all sorry for my bad English. I am designing a book and I have problems with the `bookmark` when I compile the file.tex in file.pdf. The chapters appear twice. In my code I don't want to list the chapters, but I want them to appear in the `tableofcontents` so I had to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter name}` to add them to the index, but this causes re-add the chapters in the `bookmark`

Additionally I'm using the package `bookmark` to link the chapters in the page that I desire. **What can I do to display the chapters in the tableofcontents and in the bookmark
of file.pdf once?**

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{book} 
...  
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Presentación}   % Presentation of the book
\bookmark[page=2,level=0]{Presentación}  

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Aspectos téncicos} % From here they appear in the index 
\bookmark[page=4,level=0]{Aspectos téncicos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Aspectos téncicos}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm new to this, modify the code. Do not know if it still is too much?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to append bookmark instructions for all chapters, nor `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openright]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-60pt}{10pt}[-60pt]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{28pt plus 1pt minus 2pt}{14pt plus 2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{14pt plus 1pt minus 2pt}{14pt plus 2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{14pt plus 1pt minus 2pt}{14pt plus 2pt}

% Change \frontmatter and \mainmatter not to reset the numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagestyle{empty}% no printed page numbers
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagestyle{headings}% change to suit
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{Portada} 
%\input{./portada.tex}   % Bookcover
{\Huge COVER}\clearpage %%%% <--- I don't have your file

%%% This doesn't go in the TOC, so a \bookmark is necessary   
\chapter*{Presentación}   % Presentation of the book
\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{Presentación}  

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Aspectos técnicos}   %First chapter from here I wish to appear in the tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I modified the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands in order not to reset the numbering. Using `\pagenumbering{gobble}` doesn't work when `hyperref` is involved, but it's sufficient to kill the normal page style and reset it at `\mainmatter`.

(I have also omitted the inessential packages, fill them as you prefer.)

Comment: Thanks @egreg . When compiling, does not show twice the chapters in the `bookmark`, but I put `chapter*` because I don't wish to show me the numbers and the word "chapter" in the chapters. How do I get these conditions?

Comment: @lbautista I don't see why you don't want the chapter number; however you can get rid of it by simply acting on the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` commands relative to `\chapter`. For instance, `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}`

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to avoid having to modify the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` because I'm new at this; why choose to put `chapter*`. I will try and tell him. Thanks